# Slow Query With Multiple Left Outer Joins

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query which has multiple left joins. it takes around 3.2s for execution. I have added indexes on every column which is taking part in JOIN. is it something regarding DB performance?
What all columns I need to consider for index. is a composite index needed in this case?

```
SELECT 
            COUNT(*) FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT P.PROFILE_ID
            FROM
            user.PROFILE P 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user.PROFILE_ACCOUNT P_AC ON P_AC.PROFILE_ID = P.PROFILE_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user.ACCOUNT AC ON AC.ACCOUNT_ID = P_AC.ACCOUNT_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user.PROFILE_ADDRESS SA ON SA.ADDRESS_ID = P.SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user.PROFILE_ADDRESS BA ON BA.ADDRESS_ID = P.BILLING_ADDRESS_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user.PROFILE_ADDRESS AC_BA ON AC_BA.ADDRESS_ID = AC.BILLING_ADDRESS_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user.PROFILE_ADDRESS AC_SA ON AC_SA.ADDRESS_ID = AC.SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN user.PROFILE_CUSTOM_PROPS PCP ON PCP.PROFILE_ID = P.PROFILE_ID

         WHERE P.ORGANIZATION_ID = 1
            AND P.ISANONYMOUS = false 
     )  AS T_PROF_ID;
```

Comment: You may want to include the [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html) plan, but I suspect the `DISTINCT` keyword is your major issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Are there ever two billing addresses for one account?  If not, toss the `LEFT JOIN` for that address; it has *no affect* on the `COUNT(*)`.  Ditto for all the other `LEFT JOINs`.

Even if one of the `LEFT JOINs` leads to extra rows, get rid of them because of the `DISTINCT`.

Are there multiple profiles for each user?  If not, then much of the other baggage is wasted.

Then get rid of the nested ("derived") `SELECT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)   -- or maybe COUNT(DISTINCT profile_id)
    FROM profile AS p
    WHERE P.ORGANIZATION_ID = 1
      AND P.ISANONYMOUS = false
```

That should give you the same count as your original query.  If not, please explain where there are 1:many mappings that are not obvious.

If you aren't really asking about `COUNT(*)`, but rather fetching multiple columns, then show us the *real* query; it may need other optimizations.  Also, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we don't waste time recommending indexes you may already have.